# How can I see the endorsement information on the back of cancelled checks?

Tags: united-states, check, checking-account

Back in the days when banks provided our cancelled checks, we could see how the check was endorsed and the accounts into which it was deposited by looking at the rear of the cashed check.

However, nowadays, I receive only an image of the FRONT of the check.

What do I do if I want to see the endorsed side of the check?

Comment: In my experience banks provide the image of both the front and the back, so you should probably ask your specific bank why they don't.

Comment: ... and if you don't like their answer, change banks.

Comment: My bank's web site shows both front and back.

Comment: When i deposit cheques with my phone app, i am not required to endorse or write account numbers or anything on the back of the cheque. Getting an image of the back of a cheque I deposited wouldn't help you.

Comment: @KateGregory what's to stop someone from stealing your check, and depositing it into your account?  "She gave it to me, and now she's trying to steal it from me!"

Comment: I am not following. The cheque is payable to me and I'm putting it in my account. Writing the account number on the back is no longer a required step (we never had to sign cheques on the back unless we were endorsing them for someone else) because the image is stored with a record of what account I deposited it to. And anyway, questions about why my bank doesn't make me do something aren't things I answer, they are things my bank might answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that my bank only sends me printed versions of the FRONT of the checks. However, if I use the digital online banking then I can see both sides. Also, I can request paper copies of the backs of checks if I ask customer service for it.

Answer (score 1):

> What I do if I want to see the endorsed side of the check?

Talk to your bank. If you only want to see the reverse side on a handful of checks each year, they may for a small fee be able to provide that detail. Their answer may differ if the check is cashed at one of their branches, because those checks are processed differently.

If the number of checks you want the details for is large or the fee is more than you are willing to pay, then make a request for that feature to be added. If you are lucky the option already exists in their software, and they just have to enable an option, or pay for a more expensive license.

If they can't make the change, or won't make the change, and further appeals fail, then you can research other financial institutions that have this feature.